# Github Actions not finding the library project

Tags: c#, .net, github-actions

Finally, the weekend! I have time.

I am a medical student and I made a Blazor website for my class that I set up github actions to build and then FTP the website to my hosting provider. And this worked.

I then abstracted the models into a class library project shared between the API, Blazor website and MAUI App. Hooked up everything and it works in debug and even when I publish the Blazor website as a folder (which is what I am currently having to do to push it to the hosting service) but Github Actions don't work anymore.

The error it throws is as follows

```
Run dotnet restore
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.200/NuGet.targets(414,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/home/runner/work/MedbaseBlazor/MedbaseLibrary/MedbaseLibrary.csproj" was not found. [/home/runner/work/MedbaseBlazor/MedbaseBlazor/MedbaseBlazor.sln]
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

The error seems simple to fix in my head but I don't know what to do at all. What should I do in Github actions to make sure the class library is referenced?

I tried using submodules (as in the following picture) but that hasn't worked

[image: r/dotnet -]

*Github Actions File.yml*

```
# This workflow will build a .NET project
# For more information see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-net

name: .NET

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        submodules: 'recursive'
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: 7.0.x
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --no-restore
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-build --verbosity normal
    - name: Publish
      run: dotnet publish -c Release --property:PublishDir=./Release
    - name: ftp-action
      uses: sebastianpopp/ftp-action@v2.0.0
      with:
        # Deployment destination server & path. Formatted as protocol://domain.com:port/full/destination/path/
        host: ${{ secrets.FTP_SERVER}}
        # FTP account username
        user: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME}}
        # FTP account password
        password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}
        localDir: ./Release/
```

Project setup screenshot

[image: r/dotnet - Github Actions not finding the library project r/dotnet - And yes, the library is already a dependency of the website And yes, the library is already a dependency of the website]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by uploading my class library to Nuget and using it as a nuget package.